# My redux-form is reinitialized when switching language by changing react-intl wrapper props

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-intl

I'm wrapping my app inside an `IntlProvider` from `react-intl` [v2](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/162), like this:

```jsx
<IntlProvider locale={this.props.lang} messages={this.props.messages}>
```

And I have my `react-form` forms down the tree. Everything is great.

But if I'm starting to fill up a form, and I decide to change the language of the UI (by listening to an action that will update my `lang` and `messages` props through my redux store), the form is being reset :-/

I see the action `redux-form/INITIALIZE` being fired when the lang changes.

And it happens even if I pass `destroyOnUnmount: false` to `reduxForm()`.

It did not happen with uncontrolled form fields.

Any idea?

My code: [App.js](https://github.com/antoinerousseau/mytribe/blob/master/app/App.js#L86) + [Register form](https://github.com/antoinerousseau/mytribe/blob/master/app/forms/Register.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm... You are changing your `initialValues` prop, so it's initializing the form data. `initialValues` is intended to be used for canonical data from the server to be edited (e.g. a loaded record), not really for updating individual form values from outside the component.

Perhaps you could use the [`plugin()` API](http://redux-form.com/4.2.0/#/api/reducer/plugin) to notice the language change action (is that being changed via Redux?) and update the `lang` value in your form?

Comment: It works indeed! But only with `destroyOnUnmount: false` then... I'll keep experimenting and share my results here

Comment: OK so it's fine, I just need to manually handle the cleaning of my form when unmounting then... https://github.com/antoinerousseau/mytribe/commit/7d26b850989042d46b8e0c72267e5fd1e06945e7

Comment: I found a way to keep `destroyOnUnmount: true` and still keep the initial value: by listening to the `DESTROY` and `INITIALIZE` actions of `redux-form`: https://github.com/antoinerousseau/mytribe/commit/4d39dfbdcc197ea47d77d9533065c6fb707cc55f#diff-ccdfddd88097e5403cefd300fa56e86cR22

Comment: @antoine129 can you please update your links in the comments, they are not working!

Comment: @Mohammadaltenji sorry I cannot edit my comment, and I don't have a public link to this anymore

Comment: anyway this is all outdated, please read the latest doc of redux-form

Answer (score 3):

We encountered the same issue when combining `react-relay` with `redux-form`. The solution was simple: we initialize the form when the form is mounted.

```js
compose(
  createContainer({
    fragments: {
      viewer: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on User {
          nickname
          email
        }
      `
    }
  }),
  reduxForm({
    form: "user",
    fields: ["nickname", "email"],
  })
)(
  class UserForm extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      this.props.initializeForm(this.props.viewer)
    }

    render() {
      // Same as before
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Nice solution! But in the end I like the redux-form plugins: https://github.com/antoinerousseau/mytribe/blob/master/app/utils/formPlugins.js