# How to reset (or destroy) redux-form only when route changes and keep on language switch?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, redux-saga, react-intl

I create registration/login/forgot-password forms using redux-form. Also I use react-intl for multilingual support. Changing language causes rerender of components and resets the forms.

I would like to reset form only when location is changed, but my solution seems to me not perfect

1) if I use `destroyOnUnmount: true` the case is next: when user started to fill e.g. registration form and then decided to change language -> form destroys on unmount and all fields are reset.
2) if `destroyOnUnmount: false` everything is OK, on language change form data doesn't destroy. But if to change route and then open again registration form - previous data is still present.

initialValues are not set

So I decided to set `destroyOnUnmount: false`

Then in App component I call action if location changes

```
  // reset redux forms on route change
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      this.props.resetFormsAction();
    }
  }
```

and then in saga listen to action

```
export function* resetForms() {
  try {
    const forms = yield select(getForms);
    yield all(Object.keys(forms).map(form => put(reset(form))));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

const commonSagas = [
  takeEvery(RESET_FORMS, resetForms),
];

export default commonSagas;
```

selector

```
export const getForms = (state: AppStore) => state.form;
```

This solution works fine, but is there any other implementation to reset/destroy form only when location is changed but not when change language is clicked

I have found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858406/my-redux-form-is-reinitialized-when-switching-language-by-changing-react-intl-wr?rq=1) but it didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

You can reset form in saga instead of calling own action in componentDidUpdate()

1. Set destroyOnUnmount: false
2. Instead of reset you can use 'destroy' action from redux-forms

> ```
> yield takeEvery('@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE', function* () {
>       try {
>         const forms = yield select(getForms);
>         yield all(Object.keys(forms).map(form => put(destroy(form))));
>       } catch (e) {
>         console.error(e);
>       }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! Yes, I have tried to use ```сonnected-react-router``` and to listen ```LOCATION_CHANGE``` for reset or destroy, but I see action LOCATION_CHANGE in redux dev tools also when I change language :(

Comment: Get new location from saga payload and compare with location from state, if not equal than call destroy

Comment: I checked: selector ```getLocation``` from ```сonnected-react-router``` returns the same `location`  as action.payload.location. The same result if I create my own selector for location pathname `const getLocationPathname = (state: AppStore) => state.router.location.pathname;`. Hmmm... I'll try smth else. But thanks for advice!

Comment: You can use 'select' effect to get actual location in saga and then check payload.location === yield select(state =} state.router.location)

Answer (score 0):

As a result, I decided to handle destroy in componentWillUnmount and saga.

Example

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    const { destroyFormRequestAction } = this.props;
    destroyFormRequestAction(FormTypes.registration, REGISTRATION_URL);
  }
```

and then listen action in my saga and check if route changed

```
...
export function* destroyForm(action: DestroyFormAction) {
  try {
    const routerLocation = yield select(getLocation);
    if (routerLocation.pathname !== action.payload.currentPath) {
      yield put(destroy(action.payload.formType));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e); // tslint:disable-line
  }
}

const formSagas = [
  takeEvery(DESTROY_FORM_REQUEST, destroyForm),
];
```